# How to Structure Jquery/Html project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, apache-flex

I am Flex / Action Script Developer. I am started learning Jquery and Html. I want to Structure Project using jquery ..

Let me give some sample the way i do in Flex .

---

```
           Header (separate Mxml /module swf file)
```

---

```
 Contents (separate mxml file / module Swf dynamically loaded. )
```

---

```
    Footer(Separate mxml/module swf file)
```

---

How can I achieve same kind of or similar kind of modular concept in jQuery and HTML?

Comment: you have similar head,body in html though the head is not the header. You should put visible contents within body. i.e. header, contents, footer all within body. Head has links to css files,js files, title and [meta tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_element). Header, Contents and footer should be part of `<body>`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read the help section for the types of questions this site excels at: http://stackoverflow.com/help .  I voted to close this question as it is not a specific programming question that can be answered concretely; but more one that is based on opinions and will most likely incite debate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
<html>

<head>
     <link href="your-css-file" />   
</head>

  <body>

     <header>
        // header contents here
     </header>

     <section id="page" role="main">
       // page contents here
     </section>


     <footer>
         // footer contents here
     </footer>

     <script src="your-js-file"></script>

   </body>

</html>
```

and then if you wanted to keep your jQuery for each section differently structure your js file like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   headerStuff();
   pageStuff();
   footerStuff();


   function headerStuff(){

      // do header stuff 

   }

   function pageStuff(){

      // do page stuff 

   }

   function footerStuff(){

      // do footer stuff 

   }

});
```

I would suggest looking into using this to get a better idea. Its pre set up and ready for you to code

http://html5boilerplate.com/